# IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have multiple files in 7 different folder directories. All of these files have the same name, and I want to combine those files with the same name as one file, in another directory

```
import os
from itertools import chain

paths = (r'C:/Users/Test_folder/Input/', r'C:/Users/Test_folder/Input_2/')
for path, dirs, files in chain.from_iterable(os.walk(path) for path in paths):
    for fname in paths:
        for line in fname:
                f = open(os.path.join(r'C:/Users/Test_folder/Test_output/', os.path.basename(fname)), 'a')
                f.write ('{:}\n'.format(line))
                f.close()
```

Error:

```
f = open(os.path.join(r'C:/Users/Test_folder/Test_output/', os.path.basename(fname)), 'a')
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/Test_folder/Test_output/'
>>>
```

Comment: Exactly what it says. You don't have permissions to write there

Comment: Try running it from an administrative command line or as `sudo` on *nix

Comment: there is any other way to combine two multiple directories in another directories ?

Comment: Do you have one of the files open in another program, or being used by another program?

Answer (score 0):

For issue of `permisson denied`

```
  with open(os.path.join('type filename here' , os.path.basename(line)), 'w')
```

Or

```
for filename in os.listdir(src):
   path = os.path.join(src, filename)
   with open(path, "r") as inputFile:
   content = inputFile.read()
```

Comment: @Vish permisson denied?

Comment: Error is same: `f = open(os.path.join(r'C:/Users/Test_folder/Test_output/', os.path.basename(fname)), 'a')
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/Test_folder/Test_output/'
>>>`

Comment: you use windows? Are trying to access adminstrator files from user privilage account?

Answer (score 0):

The logic of your code is wrong:

- `for fname in paths` should be `for fname in files`
- `for line in fname` will not read the file `fname` line by line as `fname` is a string, not a file object

The permission error is due to that your code try to open a `directory` for appending.

Try:

```
import os
from itertools import chain

paths = (r'C:/Users/Test_folder/Input/', r'C:/Users/Test_folder/Input_2/')
for path, dirs, files in chain.from_iterable(os.walk(path) for path in paths):
    for fname in files:
        with open(os.path.join(path, fname)) as fin, open(os.path.join('C:/Users/Test_folder/Test_output/', fname), 'a') as fout:
            fout.write(fin.read())
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using windows, re-run your ide as administrator.